# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API 400 Audio Timeout Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text

I'm trying Google Cloud Speech-to-text API to transcribe audio from interviews into text. I set a retry method that allows 3 retries if errors are found. Problem is I keep getting these "400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time" and I'm not sure where that comes from.

Console output:

```
Converted retries value: 3 -> Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /storage/v1/b/nicarg?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1" 200 727
https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /download/storage/v1/b/*****/o/******.m4a?alt=media HTTP/1.1" 200 56660932
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'mp4', '-i', 'audio\\******.m4a', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-vn', '-f', 'wav', '-'])
Authenticating credentials...
Authentication successful!
Creating a streaming recognizer...
Attempting to transcribe. Maximum retries: 3.
Loading stream...
Transcribing...
Transcribing Segments:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                             | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Error during Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API request: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.
Loading stream...
Transcribing...
Transcribing Segments:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                             | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Error during Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API request: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.
Loading stream...
Transcribing...
Transcribing Segments:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                             | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Error during Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API request: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.
Maximum retry attempts reached. Unable to transcribe the segments.
```

Full code:

```
import os
import sys
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence
from transcriber import Transcriber
import logging
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import speech
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
from google.api_core.exceptions import DeadlineExceeded, ServiceUnavailable
import random

# Constants
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH = "********.json"
BUCKET_NAME = "*****"
AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "*****.m4a"
AUDIO_PATH = os.path.join("audio", AUDIO_FILE_NAME)
REMOTE_AUDIO_PATH = AUDIO_FILE_NAME
SEGMENT_DURATION = 5 * 60000
LANGUAGE = "es-419"

class Transcriptor:
    """
    Functions to process audio into transcribable text.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def download_audio_from_cloud(audio_path, remote_path):
        client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH)
        bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

        blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
        blob.download_to_filename(audio_path)

    @staticmethod
    def split_and_transcribe(audio_path, segment_duration=SEGMENT_DURATION, language=LANGUAGE):
        """
        Splits the audio into segments and then transcribes each segment.

        Parameters:
        - audio_path (path): Audio file to process.
        - segment_duration (int): Segment duration.
        - language: Language of processing.

        Returns:
        - Audio transcripted.
        """
        Transcriptor.download_audio_from_cloud(audio_path, REMOTE_AUDIO_PATH)

        # Load audio file
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path, format="m4a")
        
        # Calculate the number of segments based on the specified duration
        num_segments = int(len(audio) / segment_duration) + 1

        # Split the audio into segments
        audio_segments = [audio[i * segment_duration:(i + 1) * segment_duration] for i in range(num_segments)]

        # Transcribe the segments using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API
        result_transcription = Transcriptor.transcribe_cloud(
            f"gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{AUDIO_FILE_NAME}", language, audio_segments, total=num_segments
        )

        return result_transcription

    @staticmethod
    def transcribe_cloud(gcs_uri, language=LANGUAGE, audio_segments=None, total=100, max_retries=3): 
        """
        Transcribes audio segments using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API.

        Parameters:
        - gcs_uri (str): Google Cloud storage URI for the audio file.
        - language: Language of processing (always set as es-419)
        - audio_segments: List of audio segments to transcribe.

        Returns:
        - Transcript of the audio segments.
        """
        
        # Authenticate credentials
        try:
            print("Authenticating credentials...")
            client = speech.SpeechClient.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH)
            print("Authentication successful!")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Authentication error: {e}. Verify Google credentials and try again.", exc_info=True)
            return None

        # Create a streaming recognizer with the given config
        print("Creating a streaming recognizer...")
        config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=16000,
            language_code=language,
            enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        )
        streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config,
            interim_results=True
        )

        num_tries = 0

        # Attempting to transcribe
        print(f"Attempting to transcribe. Maximum retries: {max_retries}.")
        while num_tries < max_retries:
            try:
                # Loading stream
                print("Loading stream...")
                requests = (
                    speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=segment.raw_data if segment else b'')
                    for segment in audio_segments
                )

                # Call the streaming_recognize method with the generator of requests
                responses = client.streaming_recognize(config=streaming_config, requests=requests)

                # Transcribing
                print("Transcribing...")
                transcript_builder = []

                # Process interim and final results
                with tqdm(total=total, desc="Transcribing Segments") as pbar:
                    for response in responses:
                        for result in response.results:
                            for alternative in result.alternatives:
                                transcript_builder.append(f"\nTranscript: {alternative.transcript}")
                                transcript_builder.append(f"\nConfidence: {alternative.confidence}\n")
                                
                            # Update the progress bar
                            pbar.update(1)

                transcript = "".join(transcript_builder)

                if transcript:
                    logging.info("Transcription successful!")
                    print(transcript)
                    return transcript
                else:
                    logging.error("Transcribing result is empty. Retrying the segments.")
                    num_tries += 1

            except DeadlineExceeded as timeout_error:
                logging.warning(f"Timeout error: {timeout_error}. Retrying the segments. Retry attempt {num_tries}/{max_retries}.")
                num_tries += 1

            except ServiceUnavailable as service_unavailable_error:
                logging.warning(f"Service Unavailable: {service_unavailable_error}. Retrying the segments.")
                num_tries += 1

            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error during Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API request: {e}")
                num_tries += 1

            # Exponential backoff: wait for a random time between 2^nums_tries seconds
            wait_time = random.uniform(0, 2**num_tries)
            time.sleep(wait_time)

        logging.error("Maximum retry attempts reached. Unable to transcribe the segments.")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set up logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/transcriptor.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

    # Set up console logging
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(console_handler)

    # Set Google Cloud credentials
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH

    # Transcribe audio and pass the text to the Transcriber
    try:
        result_transcription = Transcriptor.split_and_transcribe(AUDIO_PATH, SEGMENT_DURATION, LANGUAGE)
        app = Transcriber(result_transcription)
        app.run()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I tried everything ChatGPT proposed me without any tangible results. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem. It is likely a Speech-to-Text limit issue as defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas). According to the Google document:

> - Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.
>   ** If you need to stream content for more than 5 minutes, see the endless streaming tutorial.

From you log,

```
    https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /download/storage/v1/b/*****/o/******.m4a?alt=media HTTP/1.1" 200 56660932
```

The code is streaming a ~50MB audio file from local file path, with each segment of streaming likely larger than 5 minute (`SEGMENT_DURATION = 5 * 60000`)

A quick test to validate that you are hitting the API limit is to adjust the SEGMENT_DURATION to something smaller. For example `SEGMENT_DURATION = 5 * 30000`. You might hit error with audio size exceeds the limit, but it will confirm the audio length limit is causing the original error.

You can use [asynchronous speech recognition](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize) along with using the GCS bucket url (instead of downloading to local, passing bucket URL to API) to transcribe long audio files in batch mode.

If you still want streaming content for more than 5 minutes, you can reference the [endless streaming sample](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endless-streaming-tutorial).

Comment: As I was waiting for a response, I modified the code completely. Now I have another problem explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816944/google-cloud-storage-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-total-size