# Google Cloud Storage: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'total_size'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text

I am developping a tool to transcribe interviews for a contract I have. For that I develop a code with the following flow:

1. After input validation, the audio file (in m4a) is converted to wav and stored locally.
2. Then, the WAV file is sent to my Google Cloud Storage bucket.
3. Finally, the WAV file inside GCS is transcribed.

For the moment, step 1 works fine and step 3 is yet to be verified. I am currently having problems with the second part of the flow, as apparently google.resumable_media doesn't recognize some of the arguments I am giving it.

**main.py logging:**

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'mp4', '-i', 'audio\\*******.m4a', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-vn', '-f', 'wav', '-'])
Converted retries value: 3 -> Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
Upload url: https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/****/o?uploadType=resumable
Total size: 113932332
Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "POST /upload/storage/v1/b/******/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1" 200 0
https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "POST /upload/storage/v1/b/******/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1" 400 239
File uploaded to gs://*****/audio.wav
Error during Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API request: 404 No such object: *****/audio.wav
Full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 79, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1160, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1003, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND
    details = "No such object: *****/audio.wav"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.13.138:443 {grpc_message:"No such object: *****/audio.wav", grpc_status:5, created_time:"2024-01-16T00:11:43.0873289+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\transcriptor.py", line 57, in transcribe
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\services\speech\client.py", line 708, in long_running_recognize
    response = rpc(
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\*****\Documents\Work\IRSST Transcriptions 2024\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 81, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 No such object: nicarg/audio.wav
```

**Problematic snippet:**

```py
    @staticmethod
    def send_to_gcs(audio_file, destination_uri):
        """
        Send the converted WAV file to the GCS bucket.

        Parameters:
        - audio_file: Audio file.
        - destination_uri: Destination URI.
        """
        try:
            # Create a storage client
            print("Accessing client credentials...")
            storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH)

            # Configure resumable upload with a timeout
            try:
                print("Configuring resumable upload with a timeout...")
                upload_url = f"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{BUCKET_NAME}/o?uploadType=resumable"
                chunk_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # Adjust as needed
                total_size = os.path.getsize(audio_file)
                timeout_seconds = 5 * 60  # Adjust as needed

                upload = google.resumable_media.requests.upload.ResumableUpload(
                    upload_url,
                    chunk_size=chunk_size,
                )

                transport = AuthorizedSession(credentials=storage_client._credentials)
                logging.debug(f"Upload url: {upload_url}")
                logging.debug(f"Total size: {total_size}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error configuring resumable upload: {e}")

            # Open the audio file and perform the upload
            print("Open the audio file and performing the upload...")
            try:
                with open(audio_file, "rb") as audio_data:
                    upload.initiate(
                        transport=transport,
                        stream=audio_data,
                        metadata={
                            "name": f"{destination_uri}",
                            "Content-Type": "audio/wav"
                        },
                        total_bytes=total_size,
                        timeout=timeout_seconds,
                        content_type="audio/wav",
                    )
                    
                    # Use the http property for the request
                    transport.request(
                        method="POST",
                        url=upload_url,
                        headers=upload._headers,
                        data=upload.bytes_uploaded,
                    )
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error performing the upload: {e}")
                    
            logging.info(f"File uploaded to {destination_uri}")
            return destination_uri
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error during cloud upload: {e}")
            return None
```

I was thinking of using less recent versions of google.resumable_media but I am afraid of screwing all up, I have been modifying this code for days and I want to start transcribing as soon as possible.

EDIT 1: I made some modifications to the code according to your suggestions, but now the problem I am having is the code seems to work without errors but doesn't upload the audio file into my GCS bucket.

Comment: Why do you think `ResumableUpload` accepts an argument `total_size`?

Comment: I recommend using the [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/main). That library is the defacto Python library for Cloud Storage. Using [BlobWriter](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobWriter) will simplify your development. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#behavior) as well. If you do not want to change libraries, Gang Chen's answer looks helpful.

Comment: With your new code investigate the error `No such object: *****/audio.wav`.

Answer (score 1):

As deceze commented, ResumableUpload doesn't support total_size and timeout parameters. The [API doc](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/google-resumable-media/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.ResumableUpload) has the following signature:

```
ResumableUpload(upload_url, chunk_size, checksum=None, headers=None)
```

You might want to use the [initiate](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/google-resumable-media/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.ResumableUpload#google_resumable_media_requests_ResumableUpload_initiate) method to configure the `total_bytes` and `timeout` configuration.

Though a bit outdated, but [here](https://dev.to/sethmlarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h) is a good example of using ResumableUpload.